# how to store the output of a command into an array in expect script

Tags: expect

with little knowledge in expect scripting,I have some idea on how to assign values to an array.
But how about creating an array where I don't know the size.Say,I want to store the output of the command 'ls' in an array,How do I achieve this in expect scripting

```
set myArray [exec ls] 
for {set index 0} {$index < [array size myArray]} {incr index} {
    send "echo $myArray($index)\r" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expect` is an extension of `Tcl` and `Tcl`'s arrays are associative in nature. There is no need of specifying the size for an array.

You can straightaway add an element to the array with it's corresponding array index. It is not necessary to start with 0,1,2... and so on. It can be a string as well.

An array can be interpreted as key->value pair.

```
set userInfo(name) Dinesh
set userInfo(year) 2016
set useInfo(language) Tcl

% parray userInfo
userInfo(language) = Tcl
userInfo(name)     = Dinesh
userInfo(year)     = 2016
%
```

Say, you are executing the command `ls` by means of `exec` command. We all know the simply executing the `ls` command will give us the list of file & folder names. But, for `Tcl`'s array, we should have a key-value pair. We need a index for each of values.

For instance, we can define the array indices with numbers, like 0,1,2,.. and so on.

```
set output [exec ls]
for {set i 0} {$i<[llength $output]} {incr i} {
        set result($i) [lindex $output $i]
}

foreach idx [lsort -integer [array names result]] {
    puts "result($idx) = $result($idx)"
}
```

Instead of the above `foreach`, you can also use parray itself. But, the result won't be in integer sorted format.

**Update 1:**

You should use the `glob` command to get the list of files.

```
set files [glob -type f *]
foreach file $files {
    send "echo $file\r"
}
```

**Reference :** [array](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm)

Comment: the line set output [exec ls] is indicating an error saying invoked from within.actually i am trying to get all those file beginning with a particular string "hello"..so i actually tried set output [exec ls hello*] and it isnt working

Comment: Share your code. [glob](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm) will comes in handy to you for your scenario, where you need to get files with the name in the pattern of `hello*`.

Comment: `set myArray [exec ls hello*]
for {set index 0} {$index < [array size myArray]} {incr index} {
send "echo $myArray($index)\r"
}`

Comment: Further, update your code in the original post. `exec ls` won't return an array. Your `foreach` will never run.

Comment: okay...how do I store the output of my command that is a list of files in an array :/ @dinesh

Comment: can somebody please tell me how to get the files starting with a particular pattern ,say, hello, from a particular directory...